# Node JS reverse proxy - POST throws 404 error

Tags: node.js, odata, reverse-proxy

I have a following node js server:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var serverOne = 'http://<address>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV/';

app.use(express.static('webapp'));
app.use(express.static('./'));

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server1');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

When using GET request like `localhost:3000/AttendanceSet` it works fine. But when I call POST request like `localhost:3000/AttendanceSet` I get following error:

```
The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed404,Not Found,<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /AttendanceSet</pre>
</body>
</html>
 -
```

How should I change the code of the server to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: You only defined a get request with `app.get()`, do the same with `app.post()` and you're good to go.

Comment: You were right, your approach works. However, I am getting this message: 'failed to execute 'send' on 'xmlhttprequest'' when trying to fetch 'X-CSFR-Token. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: My first thought would be to authorize this header in your app with `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token');` You may want to have a look at which headers have to be set to properly authenticate your requests. However the client will be blocked each time it tries to interact with the API. `res.set` might work as well, see https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set for further information

Comment: Your suggestion did not work, however I noticed something. When I access `localhost:3000/` it should redirect me to this address: 'http://<address>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_ATTENDANCE_SRV/'. But also it loads `index.html` from folder `webapp` because it is defined by this line: `app.use(express.static('webapp'))`; . So by accessing address `localhost:3000/` I am doing two things at once. Could it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `app.all`, so you process all the different HTTP verbs with the same handler.

```
app.all("/*", function(req, res) {
    console.log('redirecting to Server1');
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});
```